# Substring in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to match all nodes in my graph with a property that has a value (loaded from a csv file) as a substring.

i.e If `csvline[0]` is a sub string of a property of the node `n`. Then I want to match it.

What I actually want to do is match the names with the complete names:

```
 n.property : George Michael
 csvline[0] : George
```

Then n is matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this (in versions 2.3+) using the Cypher `CONTAINS` predicate.

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name CONTAINS "George"
RETURN n;
```

Comment: I just found a solution using regular expressions. But yours looks more readable :). Thanks.

Comment: BTW Here is the regex solution `WHERE n.name =~ ('.*'+csvline[0]+'.*')`